# How to get a file upload temporary location in server using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Get a file upload temporary location in server  using jquery or only javascript .

Is it possible to get temp location of file upload in javascript itself.

In Html

```
 <input type="file" id="ProfileUserImage" class="fileInput" name="data[Profile][userImage]" onchange= "getTempLocation()">
```

In Javascript

```
 function getTempLocation() {

   // code to get temp location of file.

  }
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as the server handles file transfers.

Comment: @Blender: If I go into server side scripting  by $('file #ProfileUserImage').submit(); in Javascript .Can I retrieve location name?

Answer (score 0):

As Blender suggested, no you cannot. If you are using PHP I know that the temporary file is removed from the file system when the script terminates.

**You can still solve the problem:**

I'm making a few guesses on what you want to do but this may help:

- Using your server, you will need to save the image to a new location. This could be your own "temporary" location.
- Pass the new location back to the client, perhaps using AJAX and display the image.
- The user can then approve the image and you can then send a request to the server to save the image to a permanent location.
- If the user exists the page before approving the image then use a CRON job to remove the temporary files at a frequency suitable to you.

**EDIT :**

The PHP manual for file uploads will tell you exactly how to upload a file and move it to a new location. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). Once you have uploaded the image, save the location to you DB or in the user session, that way you can display it later on. Once your script has finished reload the page and create a HTML image element which points to the source of the new image.

If you want to do it with ajax you will need to do a file upload using an iFrame or using an XMLHttpRequest, but transferring files this way is only available in newer browsers (at least FF 3.6, IE9, not sure on Chrome). Several libraries can do this, see [here](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/). Point the ajax file uploader at the php script (same one as before), once the upload is done get the php script to return the new location as a JSON or something else if you prefer. Using Javascript you can then access the JSON and you have the file location. DONE!

What you are trying to do is not too difficult, but it is not simple either so don't expect to solve your problem in 5 minutes. The libraries for file uploading should help you and do the majority of the work for you.

Comment: Yes,I am using PHP .Can you please give a demo